# View.getId() Always return same id in listview with holder pattern

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview with EditText in each row.
I need to get the id of the focused row.
In my code, the holder.valor.getId(); always return the same id. I don't understand why!

In other activity, I want to inflate the edittext and change the keyboard type from an actionbar button.

Here is my code :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final String marca;
    final String producto;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_form, null);

            holder.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.valor = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.valor);
            holder.valor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            holder.imgCam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cambutton);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        marca = getlForm().get(position).getMarca();
        producto = getlForm().get(position).getProducto();
        final int proyectoproducto = getlForm().get(position).getProyectoProductoId();
        String valor = getlForm().get(position).getCantidad();
        if (valor == null || valor.equals("null"))
            valor = "";
        holder.item.setText(marca + "\n" + producto);
        holder.valor.setText(valor);

        // Listener : If focus lost, we insert value in db
        holder.valor.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    // update row
                    Formulario f = getlForm().get(position);
                    EditText et = (EditText) v;
                    f.setCantidad(et.getText().toString());
                    f.setSync(0);
                    FormHandler fh = new FormHandler(ctx);
                    boolean existForm = fh.existForm(f);
                    if (!existForm)
                        fh.addForm(f);
                    else
                        fh.updateForm(f);

                }else{
                    // We have the focus, we send the id in the prefs,
                    // to send it the change keyboard function
                    int editTextId = holder.valor.getId();
                    prefs.edit().putInt("metricaEtId", editTextId).commit();
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
v.getId();
```

in

```
onFocusChange(View v,....
```

Comment: I dont know why you want the id if all are equal but if you want to know the 'position' of the textedit which it had in getView() then 'set' that position with 'edittext.setTag(position)` in getView() and retrieve with `int position=v.getTag();` in onFocusChanged.

Comment: ok, but then I will lose my reference "holder" : holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

Comment: Of course not. You can leave all the same. You have to understand that when i suggest 'edittext.setTag` that that translates in getView to `holder.valor.setTag`.

Comment: I don't understand well, but I don't see the point... In onFocusChanged, I have access to position paramater. So, there is no need to do that. Then, I don't know how to get my edittext from position in my activity...

Comment: You have access to position parameter. But it is not the right position when the focus changes. Test and you will see. And test my code. And your edittext in onFocusChanged is View v. But that code is already there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56663/discussion-between-juliatzin-del-toro-and-greenapps).